# JAX-RS Sobrescribir metodo con mismo path

Tags: java, rest, rutas, jersey, jax-rs

Actualmente tengo un servicio rest genérico, que recibe todas las llamadas y las procesa de forma según el tipo de operación.

Algunas de las llamadas serian:

- /user/1/v3/personas
- /user/1/v3/maquinaria

Luego según si son post o get o incluso si llevan un sufijo en especifico se llama a un listado, inserción, búsqueda con filtros, modificación o eliminación.

La cosa es que se quiere que para una operación especifico, cuando se le pase un **POST sin ningún sufijo** (en la superclase seria un insert), se haga una búsqueda con filtros ( ya que en la superclase seria con el sufijo "/search")

```
@Path("/user/{userId}{a:\\/v3\\/|\\/}{operation}")
public class Service {

 @POST
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public Response insert(@Context final HttpHeaders httpHeaders,         
 @PathParam(USER_ID) final Integer userId,
        @PathParam(OPERATION_LABEL) final String oper, final String record) {
     //......
 }

 @POST
 @Path("/search")
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public Response search(@Context final UriInfo uriInfo, @Context final HttpHeaders httpHeaders,
        @PathParam(USER_ID) final Integer userId, @PathParam(OPERATION_LABEL) final String oper,
        final String record) {

     //...........
  }
}
```

He creado una clase nueva que tiene primero especificado el tipo de operación ("tratamientos") y luego quiero sobrescribir la clase insert, para que en vez de hacer una inserción, haga una busqueda.

```
@Path("/user/{userId}{a:\\/v3\\/|\\/}tratamientos")
public class TratamientosService extends Service {

 @POST
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 @Override
 protected Response insert(final HttpHeaders httpHeaders, final Integer userId, final String oper, final String record) {
     //..............
 }
}
```

Pero me esta dando un error de que no sobrescribe el método.

`GRAVE: Servlet [appServlet] in web application [/vnwebservicesnew] threw load() exception
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
[[FATAL] A resource model has ambiguous (sub-)resource method for HTTP method POST and input mime-types as defined by"@Consumes" and "@Produces" annotations at Java methods public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.visualnacert.ws.version.base.services.TratamientosService.insert(javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo,javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders,java.lang.Integer,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) and public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.visualnacert.ws.version.base.services.Service.insert(javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders,java.lang.Integer,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) at matching regular expression /user/([^/]+)(\/v3\/|\/)tratamientos. These two methods produces and consumes exactly the same mime-types and therefore their invocation as a resource methods will always fail.; source='org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.RuntimeResource@18a82922']`

---

### **Camino alternativo**

He intentado también que la lógica dentro de los métodos esten en otro método protected y en `TratamientosService` sobrescribir este método protected, pero a pesar de que no me salta error, al hacer la llamada, no pasa por la clase sobrescrita.

¿habria alguna forma que `@Path("/user/{userId}{a:\\/v3\\/|\\/}tratamientos")` tenga mayor prioridad que `@Path("/user/{userId}{a:\\/v3\\/|\\/}{operation}")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que en ambos casos "`tratamientos`" es (potencialmente) parte del path, solo que en un método lo capturas como un valor más del `PathParam` `operation` y en el otro no.

El sistema no puede saber que método aplicar al path.

La solución sencilla, tal vez no la mejor, es usar solo el método que captura {operation}, y hacer la llamada del otro metodo desde ahí:

```
if(operation.equals("tratamientos")){
   return llamarMetodoDeTratamientos(userId, uriInfo, httpHeaders, oper, records);
}
```